# Relational operator with optional type

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have following code which is working

```
if self.txtPhone.text == nil ||  self.txtPhone.text?.count == 0 || !validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: self.txtPhone.text!)  {
    message = "Please enter phone number"
}
```

If I change `self.txtPhone.text?.count == 0` to `self.txtPhone.text?.count > 10`

Then it is throwing compile time error

> Value of optional type 'String.IndexDistance?' (aka 'Optional') not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

it is strange !! , why it is work for `==` and not for `>` 
I know how to unwrap so please don't put that code as answer What I want is to know reason.

Comment: The reason is that Equatable works with optionals and Comparable does not. You have to unwrap the optional.

Comment: You can also try, `self.txtPhone.text?.count >= 11

`

Comment: @PPL Thanks for your response. You can put it as answer with some more description i will mark it as accepted

Comment: @dahiya_boy thanks for response but  It won't helpful  as PPL mentioned Comparable can't work with optional

Comment: @MartinR it is different question.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya: I don't think so. In `self.txtPhone.text?.count > 10` you compare an optional value with a non-optional value, that is the same problem as in the linked-to Q&A. Also the solution (unwrap the optional before comparing) is the same.

Comment: @MartinR Yes 100% you are correct. my question is then why == works then i found answer that **Equatable works with optionals** :)